Trying to test Apps Script code that needs to send WhatsApp message with Twilio
I'm trying to test a simple Apps Script code to send a WhatsApp message with Twilio. I'm sending the message to a verified number. It's not a US verified number though, as the Twilio page just says:

You are in a trial account and can only send messages and make calls to verified phone numbers.

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to test it to a verified number outside the US? I'm getting this error in Apps Script (getting no logs in Twilio):
Error Exception: Request failed for https://api.twilio.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code":63007,"message":"Twilio could not find a Channel with the specified From address","more_info":"https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/63007","s... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
sendWhatsAppMessage @ Code.gs:23
When I go to the URL provided in the error, I see that one of the possible causes are:

Sending a message using a From address for a Channel that is pending approval.

What is a channel? How do I know whether I am waiting approval for a channel?
I have also tried to use the "+" before the country codes and I tried to use them without the "+"
Here is my code:
  var accountSid = 'hidden';
  var authToken = 'hidden';
  var twilioNumber = '+13hidden';
  var recipientNumber = '+2781hidden'; 
  var message = 'message';
  
  var url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + accountSid + '/Messages.json';
  
  var payload = {
    "To": "whatsapp:" + recipientNumber,
    "From": "whatsapp:" + twilioNumber,
    "Body": message
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": payload
  };
  var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(accountSid + ':' + authToken);
  options.headers = {
    'Authorization': basicAuth
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}```


Please note that you won't be able to use the WhatsApp Business API until you upgraded your account, purchased a phone number and enabled it for WhatsApp communication.
However, our WhatsApp Sandbox provides a workaround for development purposes. With that, you can communicate with a limited number of phone numbers if they trigger the conversation with an initial message (which is different from verified phone numbers).
